# Any Snail Mail APIs Recommendations?

Tags: api

I'm building a web application and i want to send Snail Mail automatically by server side, Is there any good APIs for that? ( i don't mind about the cost )

P.S. I'll hate you if you say it's not programming related, and i bet many coders here would love to know.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any service that allows you to send letters via snail mail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223730/is-there-any-service-that-allows-you-to-send-letters-via-snail-mail)

Answer (score 14):

Here's a list of mailing services I found with APIs, or something close to it

- https://click2mail.com/ (REST and SOAP)
- http://www.postalmethods.com/ (SOAP)
- http://l-mail.com/ has an 'integration' account.  It is not clear how automatable sending a letter is.
- http://www.cfhdocmail.com/ (SOAP)
- http://www.ezgram.com/ has an HTML based interface you might be able to reverse engineer
- https://www.trypaper.com/ (REST)
- https://www.lob.com/ (REST)

Answer (score 5):

I just found [Postal Methods API](http://www.postalmethods.com/). I haven't really seen any others.